# Apache Error log with Python CGI

Tags: python, apache, shell, cgi

I'm trying to make sense of the following error in /var/logs/httpd/error_log. The error gets thrown when I start a python script from /var/www/cgi-bin via the apache web server. What I don't understand is that it does not actually look like an error but rather I/O stats. The python script fires a shell script which downloads a file with curl via subprocess.Popen. My best guess is something is amiss with the download process. Also, the error only gets raised sometimes - other times the python script and shell script run without error and the file is downloaded to the server as expected. No other error messages are given in the log.

```
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x]                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r100   174    0   174    0     0     43      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--    43
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r100   348    0   348    0     0     85      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--    85
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:56 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:57 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r100   174    0   174    0     0     49      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--    50
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:57 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:57 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r100   174    0   174    0     0     40      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--    40
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:57 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
[Mon Aug 13 05:16:57 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] \r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue in this thread: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t341052-curl-and-popen2.html

It seems the "error" output is curl reporting on its progress and is not actually an error. Putting --silent in the curl command should suppress the output. I still do not understand why it ended up in the error log.

Comment: Standard output (stdout) is piped to the error log. Its the same if you wrote `print 'hello'` in your script.